# How to specify CSV file encoding when downloading it with Tornado in Python?

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8, tornado

I want to provide users with a functionality to download CSV files, which will be created when the request is done, e.g. the user makes the request, the data is pulled from database and then the file is created. I would like to use specific encoding (UTF-8 in my case). When I don't specify the encoding, I think the server local encoding is used (in my case ascii-us). So I tried to pass the encoding as a header, but with no success - the encoding is still ascii-us. Here is my code.

```
class CsvHandler(RequestHandler):
        lines = ['line1', 'line2'] # in actual use case those lines are from DB
        def get(self):
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
            self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename)
            self.set_header('Content-Encoding', 'UTF-8')

            for line in lines:
                self.write(line.encode('UTF-8'))
```

Here are the details of the downloaded file:

> file -i my_file.csv
>   my_file.csv: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

I would like to have charset=utf8

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
class CsvHandler(RequestHandler):
    lines = ['line1', 'line2'] # in actual use case those lines are from DB
    def get(self):
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
        self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename)

        for line in lines:
            self.write(line.encode("UTF-8"))
```

Comment: tried that in the meantime, still when I check the type after download it's us-ascii

Comment: instead of encoding entire raw, encode each fields separately.

Comment: self.set_header("Content-Type", "text/csv; charset=UTF-8") try this.